# Выбрать 2 селектора(переменные) одновременно

Tags: jquery

Имеется 2 переменные внутри которых селекторы:

```
var a = селектор1;
var b = селектор2;
```

Каким способом можно выделить обе переменные на подобии такого?

```
$(a, b).click(function(){
    ... код...
});
```

Пример выше не работает.

Comment: $.merge(a,b)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Селекторы должны [объединяться](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) в одну строку через запятую `'selector1, selector2'`. Например, так:

```
var a = '#a';
var b = '#b';

$(a + ',' + b).click(function() {
    // код
});
```

Comment: ...или так: $(a).add(b).click()...

Comment: @TO220 предложите [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/668343/edit) моего ответа