# Как добавить дополнительную ссылку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть скрипт для обработки post запросов аякс.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#znum").submit(function() {
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "znum.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {
                if (msg == 'OK') {
                    result = '<div class="n">Спасибо! Наш менеджер с Вами свяжится в ближайшее время.</div>';
                    $("#fieldsop").hide();
                } else {
                    result = msg;
                }
                $('#noteop').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Могу ли я совместить дополнительный обработчик php, что минимзировать количество кода. Например вот так?

```
  $("#znum").submit(function() {
  url: "znum.php",
  $("#znum2").submit(function() {
  url: "znum2.php",
```

или больше

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Выбрать 2 селектора(переменные) одновременно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668343/186999)

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать такую функцию, которая будет инициализировать действие по кнопке

```
setSubmitZNum('');
setSubmitZNum('2');

function setSubmitZNum(strId) {
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#znum"+strId).submit(function() {
         var str = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "znum"+strId+".php",
             data: str,
             success: function(msg) {
                 if (msg == 'OK') {
                     result = '<div class="n">Спасибо! Наш менеджер с Вами свяжится в ближайшее время.</div>';
                     $("#fieldsop").hide();
                 } else {
                     result = msg;
                 }
                 $('#noteop').html(result);
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
 });
}
```

Comment: не хочет работать.

Comment: /znumabz=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F12%2Fodnobalochnyj-opornyj-acscomua.png&paramb=&paramho=&paramht=&paramhtt=&paramlnp=&parampk=&parampkd=&gruzto=&gruztd=&skorostpt=&skorostptd=&skorostppt=&skorostppk=&tempkr=&vidtg=&meseg=&first_name=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9&last_name=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE&emailg=mail%40gmail.com&tel=09.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: а, там коллизия с вашей перемнной, сейчас. Поправил

Comment: не срабатывает аякс теперь

Comment: так а что пишет? Но вообще в комментарии к вашему вопросу, ответ получше, чем этот

Comment: Оно перезагружает страницу и добавляет в адресную строку добавляет данные о том что я отправил. а акякс не рабоатет

Comment: так может сервер не отвечает?

Comment: Та все отвечает, Без этих нововведений  скрипт работает. и запросы идут. что же может быть не так?

Comment: в текущем контексте недостаточно данных, чтобы ответить на этот вопрос

Comment: так получается что скрипт как будто не рабочий. Не происходит передача в php/

Comment: может у вас не submit? Сейчас проверил на tutorialspoint, работает